# C++ DLL Procedure Entry Point Exception due to variable

Tags: c++, dll

## Code

#### DLL

```
//Service.h
#ifdef SERVICE_EXPORT
#define SERVICE_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define SERVICE_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif


namespace Core {
    typedef class SERVICE_API ServiceLocator : public boost::noncopyable { /*...*/ } Service; //Contains log, etc
    SERVICE_API extern Service service;
}
//Service.cpp
SERVICE_API Core::Service Core::service = Core::Service();
```

#### Main Program

```
//Main.cpp
#include "Service.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    Core::service.GetLog("Hello");
    return 0;
}
```

## Question

The above is a simplification of the actual code, because my problem happens at runtime, not at compilation, etc.
Whenever I launch the main program I run into a problem where it says `'The procedure entry point ?service@Core@@3VServiceLocator@1@A cound not be found in the dynamic link library'`.
I have used `dumpbin` and `DependencyWalker` to see if it is missing from the export table only to find it there.
I tried using the debug tool placing breakpoints basically all over the code, but the problem occurs even before calling the main function, however while in debug it throws `'Unhandled exception at 0x775F36E5 (ntdll.dll) in GhostRunner.exe: 0xC0000139: Entry Point Not Found.'`

Comment: And `SERVICE_API ` actually expands to what? `__declspec( dllexport )`/`__declspec( dllimport )`?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Yeah sorry, let me edit it quickly